# show that operator $A$ that $(A x)(y)=(A y)(x)$ is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $A: X \rightarrow X^{*}$ be a linear operator satisfying
> $$(A x)(y)=(A y)(x)$$
> Show that $A$ is a continuous operator, i.e. $A \in L\left(X, X^{*}\right)$.

I know that if a operator is linear and bounded then it is continuous, so i just have to show that this is bounded, right? I was thinking that $A$ is identity, can you give me a hint to show that is bounded. Or any idea to solve the problem

Comment: Have tried to use the closed graph theorem ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I didn't know that theorem, but how can i use it to solve this if i don´t have the graph?

Comment: The graph of $A$ is the subset of $X\times X^*$ consisting of $(x,Ax)$ where $x\in X.$ You can find the closed graph theorem in any textbook on functional analysis.

Comment: Probably you can solve also using uniform boundedness principle (Banach Steinhaus theorem)

Comment: this is the Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x_n \to x \in X$ and $Ax_n \to  \psi \in X^{*}$. Then for all $y \in X$,
$$\psi(y) =\lim_n (Ax_n)(y)= \lim_n (Ay)(x_n)= (Ay)(x)=(Ax)(y)\,.$$
Thus $\psi=Ax$, and we have verified that the graph of $A$ is closed.
Therefore, by the closed graph theorem, $A$ is continuous.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem_(functional_analysis)

Edit: After (slowly) typing this proof, I saw that the same suggestion was made in the comments by  Ryszard Szwarc.

Comment: You were faster by $2$ minutes, as I watch tennis at the same time. I will remove my answer, but not the comment.

Comment: After read the closed graph theorem, i could understand it,. Thank you so much both.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Of course, no need for you to remove the comment (or the answer).

Comment: @adysthemicstudent Only now I have recalled the Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem, which deals with Hilbert spaces, but the proof is the same as in your case.